# Этимология слова "какофония"

Tags: этимология

Как произошло это слово и попало в русский язык?

Comment: Я поставила минус вашему вопросу, потому что в данном виде вопрос либо очень простой (бегло погуглив, видишь слово "какофония" в словаре галлицизмов, а вопрос о происхождении очевиден), либо очень сложный (если вам нужно подробное исследование). Уточните вопрос, пожалуйста, если это правда важно, а если он для количества, то давайте лучше удалим его.

Comment: @behemothus по моему субъективному мнению этот вопрос именно соответствует критериям вопросов, которые лучше не задавать ([help/dont-ask]): *Следует задавать исключительно практические вопросы, основанные на реальных проблемах, на которые можно дать однозначно правильный ответ. Абстрактные и дискуссионные вопросы добавляют лишний «шум» .... 

Вопросы должны быть узкими — если для ответа на вопрос требуется написать книгу, он явно не для этого ресурса.*

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51608/discussion-on-question-by-aer---).

Comment: Этимология слова  далеко не всегда однозначна, часто является спорной. Если же говорить об истории вхождения  слова в язык, то об этом в этимологических словарях  пишут очень мало, всегда можно найти новый интересный материал.  Поэтому этимологические вопросы вряд ли можно отнести  к абстрактным, о которых могут устроить дискуссию  на сайте досужие люди.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово *какофония* было заимствовано из французского *cacophonie* или немецкого *Kakophonie* примерно в конце XVIII века. Изначально оно греческого происхождения: *kakophōnia* 'дурной звук, неблагозвучие' < *kakos* 'дурной, плохой' и *phōnē* 'звук'.

В музыке, стихах какофония значит негармоничное, лишённое благозвучия, сумбурное сочетание звуков: *Но и у одаренных людей могут быть ошибки, а сюита эта, простите, показалась мне какофонией…* [Андрей Седых. Далекие, близкие. Воспоминания (1979)]

*Использовались данные "Популярного словаря русского языка" А. П. Гуськова и Б. В. Сотина.*